# CodeSkulptor time delay: no attribute 'sleep'

Tags: python, time, delay, codeskulptor

In CodeSkulptor (online Python coding page) I wrote a simple code, with a time delay. So simple:

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
print("random string")
```

When I press run, I got an error message: `Line 2: AttributeError: '<invalid type>' object has no attribute 'sleep'`

Any ideas what is wrong? Or how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using http://py3.codeskulptor.org ?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing javascript.  You have to go to py3.codeskulptor.org.  Your code works fine there.

Answer (score 0):

The module `time` in *CodeSkulptor* **implements only** the `time` function:
http://www.codeskulptor.org/docs.html#Time

See the content of the module:
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user44_uEhmhATcPLOytns.py

The documentation of *CodeSkulptor3* mentions only the `time` function in the `time` module:
http://py3.codeskulptor.org/docs.html#Time

**But** the `sleep` function and other functions are present in the implementation:
http://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user301_4e5WktRmz4A193D.py

Note that in *CodeSkulptor3* all printing waits the end of the `sleep` function. So this function is probably useless if you want wait before to print.